# Vuejs transition v-on:enter. What is the "done" callback?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to pass extra parameters to the "v-on:enter" hook:

```
<transition v-on:enter="stretch($event,done?,{opacity:1,width:'400px')"></transition>
```

... in my Vue

```
methods:{
stretch: function (properties,el,done) {
    var delay = el.dataset.index * 150
    setTimeout(function () {
      Velocity(
        el,
        properties,
        { complete: done }
        )
    }, delay)
  },
```

It doesn't work because I don't know how to pass explicitly the **done** callback (which is mandatory with the hook **enter**)

What's working but is not reusable:

`<transition v-on:enter="stretch"></transition>`
...

```
methods:{
stretch: function (el,done) {
    var delay = el.dataset.index * 150
    setTimeout(function () {
      Velocity(
        el,
        { opacity: 1, width: 400px },
        { complete: done }
        )
    }, delay)
  },
```

The link in the documentation : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks

Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the name of a method? What do you want to pass?

Comment: What is an event v-on:enter? Can you explain what exactly you want to handle with this event on div?

Comment: I want to trigger a VelocityJS animation. The 2 additional parameters are the css values I want to animate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution :

```
<transition v-on:enter="stretch(arguments, {opacity:1,width:'400px'})">`</transition>

methods: {
  stretch(args, properties) {
    // args[0] === el
    // args[1] === done()
  }
}
```

Hope it will serve.

Comment: Very interesting solution! Don't know if there are any hidden obstacles of such solution but currently it works as expected. Will vote it up. Suggest you even to mark it as an answer

Comment: You should note that this answer was actually provided to you in another forum.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation Vue.js v2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks) transition hook **enter** accepts only two parameters, those are:

- element
- done callback

Also

> When using JavaScript-only transitions, the done callbacks are required for the **enter** and **leave** hooks. Otherwise, they will be called synchronously and the transition will finish immediately.

So you can't pass any other parameters the way you've tried. But you can use **v-bind** for it. In such case your example will be something like this

html

```
<transition v-on:enter="stretch" v-bind="styles={opacity:1,width:'400px'}"></transition>
```

and js

```
data : {
...
  styles: {}
},
methods: {
...
  stretch: function (el,done) {
    var delay = el.dataset.index * 150;
    setTimeout(function () {
      Velocity(
        el,
        this.styles,
        { complete: done }
        )
    }, delay);
  },
```

Comment: Thanks Geogiy I've been given another solution I post it in answer below.